# Hypergeometric when there are 2 subjects

Tags: statistics, hypergeometric-function

How do I calculate the probability of Hypergeometric function when there are 2 subjects. For example: if there are player 1 and player 2 playing a deck of 52 cards and each of the players takes 8 cards alternately (player 1 takes one card and then player 2 takes 1 card so on until each of the players get 8 cards). what is the probability that each of the players got at least 1 spade (either black or red)?

Comment: $1$ minus the probability that neither got a spade.

Comment: "*...got at least 1 spade (either black or red)*"  Uhm... you do realize that every spade is black, right?  Your question seems to imply that you think that there are red spades.  Did you change examples in the middle of writing this and you meant to ask bout the probability that each of the players got a king which can actually be either black or red or something similar?